# Recursively dividing a list of dates into groups

Tags: postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have a list of start dates as below -

[start dates sorted in descending order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZyoT.png)

The start dates are always sorted in descending order.
I am looking for a postgresql query that can give the following output -
[start dates with groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LD1h.png)

Basically i am trying to create groups of dates from the given list such that each date in a group is within 61 days from the date at the top of the corresponding group.
For example -
in the output,

- Group 1 has first 4 records because all 4 start dates are within 61
  days of record no. 2.
- Group 2 contains only record no. 6 since it is    more than 61 days
  away from record no. 2.
- Group 3 contains row no. 7    and 8 since    they are more than 61
  days away from record no. 6. but    within 61    days of each other

P.S. I am new to postgresql and stackoverflow.
Any pointers will be helpfull

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Will keep that in mind. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample data does not match your sample output.

Your calculations in your sample output are wrong since this counts backwards and March and October both have 31 days.

To recurse properly you need to assign row numbers using `dense_rank()`:

```
with recursive num as (
  select row_number() over (order by start_date desc) as rn,
         start_date
    from dateslist
),
```

Then you create groups and find gaps by carrying anchor values forward as you recurse.  Since you have the `start_date` information you can calculate the offset within groups at the same time:

```
find_gaps as (
  select rn as anchor, start_date as anchor_date, rn, start_date, 0 as group_offset
    from num 
   where rn = 1
  union all
  select case 
           when f.anchor_date - n.start_date > 61 then n.rn
           else f.anchor
         end,
         case 
           when f.anchor_date - n.start_date > 61 then n.start_date
           else f.anchor_date
         end,
         n.rn, n.start_date, 
         case 
           when f.anchor_date - n.start_date > 61 then n.start_date
           else f.anchor_date
         end - n.start_date
    from find_gaps f
    join num n on n.rn = f.rn + 1
)
```

The final query selects the columns you want for the output and applies a group number.

```
select start_date, 
       dense_rank() over (order by anchor) as group_number,
       group_offset
  from find_gaps
 order by start_date desc;
```

[Working Fiddle Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6opXrtd9muc9RvZCj938NS/1)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This is exactly what i needed

Comment: I am new to recursive queries. Can you please help with a little more explanation. i tried testing with the following dates ('09-02-2018 00:00'),
('07-05-2021 00:00'),
('07-05-2021 00:00'),
('07-06-2021 00:00'),
('07-24-2019 00:00') - but am getting two extra records in the output

Comment: @AnindyaMukherjea That duplication is caused by the fact that `2021-07-05` is entered twice in your data.  If you change the `union all` to just `union`, that will cause the recursive CTE to eliminate duplicates.  Please see updated fiddle here:  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6opXrtd9muc9RvZCj938NS/2

Comment: now it removes one row from the output. Input has 12 rows but output has 11 rows. It seems the output can be thought of as a dictionary. Keeping union all and a left outer join seems to solves the issue - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6opXrtd9muc9RvZCj938NS/3

Comment: @AnindyaMukherjea  I am sorry.  I gave you a bad fix.  Leave the `union all`, but in the top cte, `num`, change `dense_rank()` to `row_number()`.  I would update the DB-fiddle, but it looks like the site is not working now.  I will update my answer, above.